# Issue while removing automatically added characters to custom PhoneNumberTextWatcher (XXX) XXX-XXXX

Tags: android, android-edittext

My code is working fine when formatting text in `(XXX) XXX-XXXX` format. But when removing characters, it stops once reached to character `-/()`. If I again put cursor to any number characters `-/()` will automatically get removed.

Here is code I used.

```
public class PhoneNumberTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private static final String TAG = PhoneNumberTextWatcher.class
            .getSimpleName();
    private EditText edTxt;
    private boolean isDelete;

    public PhoneNumberTextWatcher(EditText edTxtPhone) {
        this.edTxt = edTxtPhone;
        edTxt.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                    isDelete = true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                  int after) {
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (isDelete) {
            isDelete = false;
            return;
        }
        String val = s.toString();
        String a = "";
        String b = "";
        String c = "";
        if (val != null && val.length() > 0) {
            val = val.replace("-", "");
            val = val.replace("(", "");
            val = val.replace(" ", "");
            val = val.replace(")", "");
            if (val.length() >= 3) {
                a = val.substring(0, 3);
            } else if (val.length() < 3) {
                a = val.substring(0, val.length());
            }
            if (val.length() >= 6) {
                b = val.substring(3, 6);
                c = val.substring(6, val.length());
            } else if (val.length() > 3 && val.length() < 6) {
                b = val.substring(3, val.length());
            }
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (a != null && a.length() > 0) {
                if (a.length() == 3) {
                    stringBuffer.append("("+a+")"+" ");
                }
                else{
                    stringBuffer.append(a);
                }
            }
            if (b != null && b.length() > 0) {
                stringBuffer.append(b);
                if (b.length() == 3) {
                    stringBuffer.append("-");
                }
            }
            if (c != null && c.length() > 0) {
                stringBuffer.append(c);
            }
            edTxt.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            edTxt.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
            edTxt.setSelection(edTxt.getText().toString().length());
            edTxt.addTextChangedListener(this);
        } else {
            edTxt.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            edTxt.setText("");
            edTxt.addTextChangedListener(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What Exactly You Want To Do ? Remove - Char ? Or it must be after 3rd place

Comment: It happens because your onKeyEvent will never be called hence you have to handle delete event manually and format your string accordingly. You can  detect delete event my matching length of text. e.g save the length of text in some variable beforeTextChanged and then checking if the length of your typed text in afterTextChanged is less than that or not.

Comment: Formatting inputted numbers is working perfectly. I am facing issue while removing character, I added to format number. Means, while I remove last 4 numbers it won't remove -, same issue when removing ().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to listen for `Delete` key. Just store the previous value of edittext and compare it with new when `afterTextChanged` is called. Code below works great in my project. I have modified it for `(XXX) XXX-XXXX` format. You can modify the logic to specify when to delete special characters `(`, `)` and `-`.

**PhoneNumberTextWatcher:**

```
public class PhoneNumberTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private EditText phoneNumberEditText;
    private String phoneNumber = "";

    public PhoneNumberTextWatcher(EditText editText) {
        phoneNumberEditText = editText;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String newValue = s.toString();

        if (newValue.length() > phoneNumber.length()) {
            phoneNumber = s.toString();

            if (phoneNumber.length() == 4) {
                if ('(' != phoneNumber.charAt(0)) {
                    phoneNumberEditText.setText("(" + phoneNumber.substring(0, phoneNumber.length() - 1) + ") " + phoneNumber.substring(phoneNumber.length() - 1));
                    phoneNumberEditText.setSelection(phoneNumber.length());
                }
            } else if (phoneNumber.length() == 10) {
                phoneNumberEditText.setText(phoneNumber.substring(0, phoneNumber.length() - 1) + "-" + phoneNumber.substring(phoneNumber.length() - 1));
                phoneNumberEditText.setSelection(phoneNumber.length());
            }
        }
        else if (newValue.length() < phoneNumber.length()) {
            phoneNumber = s.toString();

            if (phoneNumber.length() == 10) {
                phoneNumberEditText.setText(phoneNumber.substring(0, phoneNumber.length() - 1));
                phoneNumberEditText.setSelection(phoneNumber.length());
            }
            else if (phoneNumber.length() == 6) {
                phoneNumberEditText.setText(phoneNumber.substring(1, phoneNumber.length() - 2));
                phoneNumberEditText.setSelection(phoneNumber.length());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Let me check for this. But PhoneNumberEditText doesn't seem to android.

Comment: @NikitaShah Ooh, yes. That was the custom EditText I was using in my project. Just change it to usual `EditText`. See my updated answer

Comment: @NikitaShah Glad to hear that! Consider accepting my edit. Happy coding)